# Массив JSON

Tags: json, php, массивы

```
$json = '{"new_name":"Андрей", "old_name":"Петя"}';
```

Как превратить это в массив, чтобы можно было посмотреть элементы через print_r()?

Comment: А поискать пробовали?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) вам в помощь.

```
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```